# Linq list of lists to single list

Tags: c#, linq

Seems like this is the kind of thing that would have already been answered but I'm unable to find it.

My question is pretty simple, how can I do this in one statement so that instead of having to new the empty list and then aggregate in the next line, that I can have a single linq statement that outputs my final list. details is a list of items that each contain a list of residences, I just want all of the residences in a flat list.

```
var residences = new List<DAL.AppForm_Residences>();
details.Select(d => d.AppForm_Residences).ToList().ForEach(d => residences.AddRange(d));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge a list of lists with same type of items to a single list of items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191054/how-to-merge-a-list-of-lists-with-same-type-of-items-to-a-single-list-of-items)

Answer (score 416, accepted):

You want to use the `SelectMany` extension method.

```
var residences = details.SelectMany(d => d.AppForm_Residences).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. @JaredPar has the selection from the wrong element, but thank you both for your guidance.

Answer (score 69):

Use SelectMany

```
var all = residences.SelectMany(x => x.AppForm_Residences);
```

Answer (score 53):

Here is a sample code for you:

```
List<int> listA = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

List<int> listB = new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

List<List<int>> listOfLists = new List<List<int>> { listA, listB };

List<int> flattenedList = listOfLists.SelectMany(d => d).ToList();

foreach (int item in flattenedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

And the out put will be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
11
12
13
14
15
16
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 35):

And for those that want the query expression syntax: you use two **from** statements

```
var residences = (from d in details from a in d.AppForm_Residences select a).ToList();
```