# Return list of specific property of object using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-query-syntax

Given a class like this:

```
public class Stock
{
    public Stock() {}
    public Guid StockID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say I now have a `List<Stock>`. If I would like to retrieve a list of all the StockIDs and populate it into a IEnumerable or IList. Obviously I can do this.

```
List<Stock> stockItems = new List<Stock>();
List<Guid> ids = new List<Guid>();

foreach (Stock itm in stockItems) 
{
    ids.Add(itm.StockID);
}
```

But is there some way I could use Linq to achieve the same result? I thought `Distinct()` might do it but couldn't work out how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
var list = stockItems.Select(item => item.StockID).ToList();
```

Comment: Lol, well now I feel like an idiot. I should have worked that out. Thank you!

Comment: How can I do the inverse process?

Comment: @Pedro77 using `.Reverse()`?

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it like this:

```
ids = stockItems.ConvertAll<Guid>(o => o.StockID);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? Can this be simplified?

```
List<TranCode> alltrans = new List<TranCode>();

foreach (var bh in obj1.obj2WithCollection.obj2Collection)
{
    alltrans.AddRange(bh.obj3WithCollection.Select(e => e.TransactionCode).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Try use the `SelectMany()` function like this `obj1.obj2WithCollection.obj2Collection.SelectMany(bh => bh.obj3WithCollection.Select(e => e.TransactionCode));`
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191054/how-to-merge-a-list-of-lists-with-same-type-of-items-to-a-single-list-of-items?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa