# Get value from a linq query(need idea/suggestion)

Tags: c#, linq

I need help in getting value from my linq query.
Using firstordefault()

```
var item = (from o in db.Employee
                    join a in db.EmployeeLineManager on o.Id equals a.EmployeeID
                    where o.Id == Id
                    select new
                    {
                        AddedBy = o.LastName + " " + o.FirstName,
                        LineManagerId = a.LineManagerId,
                        Email = o.Email
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I can get what is in the item(e.g if I want to get email, I can use item.Email)

But, if I use ToList()

```
var item = (from o in db.Employee
                    join a in db.EmployeeLineManager on o.Id equals a.EmployeeID
                    where o.Id == Id
                    select new
                    {
                        AddedBy = o.LastName + " " + o.FirstName,
                        LineManagerId = a.LineManagerId,
                        Email = o.Email
                    }).ToList();
```

How do I get value from the item(e.g i want to get the Email, item.Email does not work, please what can I use to get the values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return list of specific property of object using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574376/return-list-of-specific-property-of-object-using-linq)

Comment: In the second case `item` is a *list* of items. It should be named `items` to avoid any confusion. You can access its contents just like any other list or array, eg `items[0].Email` or `foreach(var item in items){ item.Email.....}`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example, `item` is a single object.  In the second example it is a *list* of objects.  (As the name implies, `ToList` converts the results *to* a *list*.)

`List<T>` has no property called `Email`.  But it does contain zero or more elements which do in this case.

So you might do something like:

```
item.FirstOrDefault().Email
```

or perhaps:

```
item[0].Email
```

or you could loop over the list, etc.

A couple things to keep in mind:

1. `item` is the wrong name at this point.  It's a collection, so call it `items`.  Variable names are important for you to understand your own code.
2. The list *might* be empty, in which case both of the above example usages would throw an exception.  You should always do some measure of `null` checking.  For example:

   ```
   items.FirstOrDefault()?.Email
   ```

Comment: In regards to the null checking, an exception may be the desired outcome here. But you would expect a clear exception message (and/or type), rather than a null reference exception which doesn't tell the consumer exactly _what_ went wrong. So a check+clear message is still needed, but that doesn't inherently mean you need to avoid exceptions as a whole.