# How do merge a list of lists conditionally

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

My question is similar to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191054/how-to-merge-a-list-of-lists-with-same-type-of-items-to-a-single-list-of-items)

```
List<List<T>> listOfList;
       // add three lists of List<T> to listOfList, for example
       /* listOfList = new {
            { "Name 1", 1, 2}, 
            { "Name 1", 3, 4}, 
            { "Name 2", 1, 2}  
            };
       */
```

I want to know how to merge items with the same names

```
       List<T> list = { { "Name 1", 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { "Name 2", 1, 2 } };
```

I tried the method Concat, but I don't know how do make a condition.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you consider _similar_?

Comment: The "Name" (ex. Name 1, Name 2);

Comment: Does this code even compile? Is ``Name`` a string? If so, why isn't it in quotes?

Comment: @WillianCândido: So is `"Name1 1"` also similar to `"Name2 2"`? However, you could use [levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to calculate similarity. But that would be inefficient since you would need to compare every item with all the others.

Comment: Given the desired output, I think he means that one "Name 1" is similar (identical in fact) to another "Name 1" and he just wants to group all distinct numerical entries under "Name 1". "Name 2" entries remain a separate bunch. But it's hard to know for sure, because the question is so imprecise.

Comment: @Konrad Morawski that is exactly what I want, sorry for the confuse question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
List<List<string>> listOfList = new List<List<string>>(){
           new List<string>() { "Name 1", "1", "2"}, 
           new List<string>() { "Name 1", "3", "4"}, 
           new List<string>() { "Name 2", "1", "2"}  
     };
```

code:

```
var result = listOfList.GroupBy(l => l.First(), 
                               (key, values) => values)
                       .Select(l => l.Aggregate((acc, next) =>
                                                 acc.Concat(next.Skip(1))
                                                    .ToList()))
                       .ToList();
```

results in:

[image]

*Explanation*: LINQ `GroupBy` operator groups `List`s with respect to the `First` element. For each group, only `values` are selected (key is not relevant as it is one of the values). Then, for each group, we `Aggregate` all lists by `Concat` them, but omitting (`Skip(1)`) the first element, which contains name.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Konrad Kokosa's solution (`SelectMany` instead of `Aggregate`):

```
        List<List<string>> listOfList = new List<List<string>>()
        {
            new List<string>() { "Name 1", "1", "2"}, 
            new List<string>() { "Name 1", "3", "4"}, 
            new List<string>() { "Name 2", "1", "2"}  
        };
        var result = listOfList
            .GroupBy(grp => grp.First())
            .Select(grp => new List<string>{ grp.Key }.AsEnumerable().Concat(grp.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))).ToList())
            .ToList();
```