# Retrieve a list B from a list A

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have two classes.

```
class Lead
{
    public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

class Activity
{
    public long ActivityId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to extract all the `List<Activity>` from `List<Lead>` in one single `List<Activity>`.

```
List<Lead> leads;
List<Activity> Activities = leads.[--Some Linq Code--];
```

Any help & suggestion are welcome.

Comment: "extract all the List from List in one single List" What? What do you want to extract? Can you please re-formulate?

Comment: *i need to extract all the List* isnt `Activities` already all the list?

Comment: Is this the same as the following? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge a list of lists with same type of items to a single list of items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191054/how-to-merge-a-list-of-lists-with-same-type-of-items-to-a-single-list-of-items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var allActivities = leads.SelectMany(x=>x.Activities);
```

Comment: For completeness of the answer You might consider adding comprehension syntax version.

Comment: What is comprehension syntax? You mean query syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
List<Activity> Activities = leads.SelectMany(s => s.Activities).ToList();
```