# Linq join with array

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 classes:

```
public class Disciplina
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Semestr { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public List<int> TimeToAll { get; set; }
    public string Otchetnost { get; set; }
    public int Specialnost { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Cafedra
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Facultet { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public List<int> Specializations { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Specialization
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SpecialName { get; set; }
    public string FormaObuch { get; set; }
    public string[] DisplinsID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I need to choose all Disciplina of chosen cafedra. I created by many foreach but I need it with linq.

I tried, but one Cafedra can have a lot of Specialization, and the Specialization can have a lot of Disiplins and I do not know how it can be chosen in a LINQ?

My method

```
private static void DiscipliniCafedri()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Выберите кафедру:");
    for (int i = 0; i < Cafedras.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + 1 + " " + Cafedras[i].ToString());
    }
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    List<Specialization> spesc = new List<Specialization>();
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Дисциплины выбранной кафедры:");

    foreach (int s in Cafedras[ID - 1].Specializations)
    {
        spesc.Add(Specializations[s - 1]);
    }

    foreach (Specialization s in spesc)
    {
        foreach (string d in s.DisplinsID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Disciplinas[Convert.ToInt32(d) - 1].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Selectmany eg cagedra.selectmany(c=>c.specilation )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq list of lists to single list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145558/linq-list-of-lists-to-single-list)

Comment: In English, "кафедра" would be "department", and "дисциплина" is usually translated as "subject" in the context of modeling a university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINQ equivalent would be:

```
var resultSet = Cafedras[ID - 1].Specializations
                .Select(s => Specializations[s - 1])
                .SelectMany(s => s.DisplinsID);

foreach(var d in resultSet)
     Console.WriteLine(Disciplinas[Convert.ToInt32(d) - 1].Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting nested loops does not require a join - you can do a sequence of `Select` calls instead:

```
var res = Cafedras[ID - 1]
    .Specializations
    .Select(s => Specializations[s - 1])
    .SelectMany(s => Disciplinas[Convert.ToInt32(s.DisplinsID) - 1].Name)
    .ToList();
```

Above,

- First `Select` represents the first loop that creates `specs`
- Second `SelectMany` represents the two nested loops.

This produces `List<string>` in the `res`, with subject names that could be printed.

Comment: DisplinsID is to array. 
I made like Aomine with one more select. Thanks!  var resultSet = Cafedras[ID - 1].Specializations
               .Select(s => Specializations[s - 1])
               .SelectMany(s => s.DisplinsID).Select(s => Disciplinas[Convert.ToInt32(s) - 1]);